# amCharts: gridlayout in axis container is not responsive

Tags: reactjs, typescript, amcharts, amcharts5

Im working in typescript and react and I want to create a graph where i have a top part of the graph containing 2 line series, and a bottom part containing of an additional series (see Picture 1)
[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RU26C.png)

The catch of the chart is that the bottom part of the chart has a fixed height on load of the graph, and the top part of the graph needs to be dynamic (so i dont want to pass a hard coded height to these axes).

I created a chart to demonstrate my problem:

```
export const FlowPressureStatusWithoutReam: FC<Props> = ({ rootId }) => {
  const dataset1 = getLineSeriesDataSet();
  const dataset2 = getLineSeriesDataSet();
  const dataset3 = getLineSeriesDataSet();

  const [chartAndRoot, setChartAndRoot] = useState<{
    root: Root;
    chart: XYChart;
  }>();

  const [axisComponents, setAxisComponents] = useState<{
    yAxisFlow: IXYAxis;
    yAxisPressure: IXYAxis;
    yAxisMotorSpeed: IXYAxis;
    xAxis: IXYAxis;
  }>();

  /* ***** Define chart and root ***** */
  useEffect(() => {
    const root = Root.new(rootId);

    const chart = root.container.children.push(XYChart.new(root, {}));

    chart.leftAxesContainer.set(
      'layout',
      // GridLayout.new(root, { fixedWidthGrid: true, maxColumns: 2 })
      root.verticalLayout
    );

    setChartAndRoot({ root, chart });

    return () => {
      root.dispose();
    };
  }, [rootId]);

  /* ***** Define Axes ***** */
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!chartAndRoot) return;
    const { chart, root } = chartAndRoot;

    const xAxis = chart.xAxes.push(
      DateAxis.new(root, {
        baseInterval: { count: 1, timeUnit: 'hour' },
        renderer: AxisRendererX.new(root, {}),
      })
    );

    const yAxisFlow = chart.xAxes.push(
      ValueAxis.new(root, {
        renderer: AxisRendererY.new(root, {}),
        marginTop: 50,
        background: Rectangle.new(root, { stroke: color('#f00') }),
      })
    );

    const yAxisPressure = chart.xAxes.push(
      ValueAxis.new(root, {
        renderer: AxisRendererY.new(root, {}),
        marginTop: 50,
        background: Rectangle.new(root, { stroke: color('#0f0') }),
      })
    );

    const yAxisMotorSpeed = chart.xAxes.push(
      ValueAxis.new(root, {
        renderer: AxisRendererY.new(root, {}),
        background: Rectangle.new(root, { stroke: color('#00f') }),
        marginTop: 50,
        height: 150,
      })
    );

    setAxisComponents({ yAxisFlow, yAxisMotorSpeed, yAxisPressure, xAxis });
  }, [chartAndRoot]);

  /* ***** Define series ***** */
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!chartAndRoot) return;
    const { chart, root } = chartAndRoot;

    if (!axisComponents) return;
    const { xAxis, yAxisFlow, yAxisPressure, yAxisMotorSpeed } = axisComponents;

    const flowSeries = chart.series.push(
      LineSeries.new(root, {
        xAxis,
        yAxis: yAxisFlow,
        valueYField: 'value',
        valueXField: 'timestamp',
      })
    );

    flowSeries.data.setAll(dataset1);

    const pressureSeries = chart.series.push(
      LineSeries.new(root, {
        xAxis,
        yAxis: yAxisPressure,
        valueYField: 'value',
        valueXField: 'timestamp',
      })
    );

    pressureSeries.data.setAll(dataset2);

    const motorSpeedSeries = chart.series.push(
      LineSeries.new(root, {
        xAxis,
        yAxis: yAxisMotorSpeed,
        valueYField: 'value',
        valueXField: 'timestamp',
      })
    );

    motorSpeedSeries.data.setAll(dataset3);
  }, [axisComponents, chartAndRoot, dataset1, dataset2, dataset3]);

  return <div id={rootId} style={{ width: '100%', height: '800px' }} />;
};
```

[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygydh.png)

As you can see, only the bottom axis has a fixed height and the top 2 axes scale based on how the bottom axis is.

But as in the first picture i attached, i want 2 axes to be next to each other and the third axis to be on the bottom. I had an idea to make the layout of the leftAxesContainer a grid:

```
    chart.leftAxesContainer.set(
      'layout',
      GridLayout.new(root, { fixedWidthGrid: true, maxColumns: 2 })
    );
```

But as i do this, the top row of the grid takes a height of +- 100% and the bottom axis just disappeares (see Picture 3)

[Picture 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPpdu.png)

Is there a way to solve this problem? Thanks in advance